# Where is media folder Id stored in Umbraco database?

Tags: umbraco

URL for an image in Umbraco looks like /media/[Media Folder ID]/[Image name].[Image extension]

Where can I find this [Media Folder ID] in the database?

Comment: Not sure where in the database it is stored but anything created in umbraco has an ID field in Properties Tab which gets used everywhere.

Comment: Why do you need to find the ID in the database?...

Comment: I needed SQL script to export all information about uCommerce products including URLs of their images. 
I've already found that URLs of the images from Media library Umbraco stores in dataNtext field of cmsPropertyData table.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, Umbraco doesn't store media image folder in the DB.

You can refer to this post to find out where the default media folder is defined:
https://our.umbraco.org/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/77409-upload-media-files-to-folder-extend

The 4 digit ID media folder names found in the "Media" folder are referenced in the various content parts in the DB depending where you have added the particular images (as properties on the nodes).